# EXCEPT on Specific columns Spark 1.6

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to filter out rows from dfA using dfB.

dfA:

```
+----+---+----+------------+-----+
|year|cid|X|        Y|Z|
+----+---+----+------------+-----+
+----+---+----+------------+-----+.
```

dfB:

```
+----+---+
|year|cid|
+----+---+
+----+---+
```

My goal is to fillter all couples `year cid` in dfB from dfA.

I see it as a clear case of except:

```
dfA.except(dfB)
```

However I need the number of columns the same in both DF.
Is there a way to perform except operation on specific columns?
Or should take another path entirely.

Comment: you can do left outer join of dfA with dfB

Comment: what you need is a left-anti join

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Seems like overkill no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, I don't think that works with `except`. what you need is a left-anti join:

```
dfA.join(dfB,Seq("year","cid"),"leftanti")
```

prior to spark 2, this should do the same

```
dfA.join(dfB.withColumn("b",lit(1)),Seq("year","cid"),"left")
  .where($"b".isNull).drop($"b")
```

Comment: is left anti join part of spark 1.6?

Comment: @user3741859 no

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that I didn't mentioned it in the title I'm on spark 1.6 just edit the question

Comment: It's not suppose to be notNull you want to drop everything that match?

Comment: @user3741859 you want all the rows which do not appear in dfB, right? In this case you must keep those from dfA which have no match in dfB, ie. where b is null...

Comment: @RaphaelRoth it will be helpful to describe your answer